# Json image not showing in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am developing a meme app in which you can share memes. I have used
"https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme"
for API. Whenever I try to run the code I do not get the image.
I am new to kotlin and stuck in this for hours

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.memeapp


import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide





class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

}
private fun loadMeme(){
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    val url = "https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme"

    

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.GET, url,null,
        { response ->
            val url = response.getString("url")

            val meme:ImageView= findViewById(R.id.memeImageView)
            print(url)
            Glide.with(this).load(url).into(meme)



        },
        {

        })


    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)

}




fun nextMeme(view: View) {

}
fun shareMeme(view: View) {

}

}
```

the image is not showing but the buttons are showing, Note: the buttons are currently null.

Comment: image url from your sample returns 404 . `"https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme"` returns json with property`"url":"https://i.redd.it/059le59uck771.jpg"` and if you try open `https://i.redd.it/059le59uck771.jpg` by browser you will see that image is not available (404 not found) .

Comment: yeah it provides random image  from Reddit , but when I try to open with browser it opens

Answer (score 0):

```
// Request a string response from the provided URL.
val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
    Request.Method.GET, url,null,

     Response.Listener {response ->
        val url = response.getString("url")
        Glide.with(this).load(url).into(meme)
    },
Response.ErrorListener{
 Toast.makeText(this,"Something wrong", Toast.LENGTH_lONG).show()
})
queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)

}
```